# Calculating datetime around weekends and evenings

Tags: sql, sql-server

SSMS 2017

I'm attempting to calculate turnaround time between a file upload and file completion date, not including time after work or on weekends

I'm trying to do this with a case statement.

```
case 
when datepart(dw,d.sduploadeddate) in (2, 3, 4, 5) and datepart(hh,d.sduploadeddate) > 16  then d.sduploadeddate+1
when datepart(dw,d.sduploadeddate) in (6) and datepart(hh,d.sduploadeddate) > 17  then d.sduploadeddate+3
when datepart(dw,d.sduploadeddate) in (7)   then d.sduploadeddate+2
when datepart(dw,d.sduploadeddate) in (8)   then d.sduploadeddate+1
else d.sduploadeddate 
end [Uploadeddatetime2]
```

The above code is working without error, but its not solving the problem obviously - its just cutting down slightly on the turnaround time. I was just tinkering with a method to get a slightly more accurate turnaround time.

The working hours are 8 --> 1700, Monday -- Friday

Ideally I'd be able to say like if this date time is past 1700, then date+1 and hours = 800 (so Thursday at 1850, change it to Friday at 800). Similarly, Friday (or any weekday) before time 800 adjust to 800 of that same day.

For Friday and weekend days the same thing, but date +1,2 or 3 depending on the day and setting it up for 800 on Monday

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used there.)

Comment: microsoft sql server management studio 17

Comment: The version of management studio is not necessarily the same version as the database engine, unless its a single local install. Management studio is just a means of interfacing with the database engine.

Comment: open query window and execute `select @@version` to get the sql server version.

Comment: what - no holidays? What happens with a disaster occurs and it takes a day to bring the DR site up?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)   Nov 30 2018 12:57:58   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )